# Converting exponential string to decimal in Datatable Select

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, decimal, exponent

I'm trying to convert the exponential string value to decimal and compare it with another decimal value inside datatable `Select` function.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("8.83567E-05");

string userInput = "8.83567E-05";

var matchedRows = dt.Select("Convert([Salary],'System.Decimal') = " + Decimal.Parse(userInput, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float));
```

But I got the below error

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

So after some research I found that using `System.Double` will work in my case

```
var matchedRows = dt.Select("Convert([Salary],'System.Double') = " + Decimal.Parse(userInput, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float));
```

and it worked.

But I don't want to use `double` as it is stores the data approximately. My data can have up to 10 decimal places.

Is there a way to convert the string exponential string value to decimal datatype ? or is it safe to use double in my case ?

Comment: You may want to consider using LINQ with something like `dt.Rows.Where(row => row.Field<decimal>("Salary") == Decimal.Parse(userInput, ...)` instead of `Select` so you have more control over the conversion.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Thank you, totally forgot about linq. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8), using double is the correct way.
(The `Expression` property is using the same syntax as filter in the `Select` method of the `DataTable`)

> Real literals using scientific notation, such as 4.42372E-30, are
>   parsed using System.Double.
>
> Real literals without scientific notation, but with a decimal point,
>   are treated as System.Decimal. If the number exceeds the maximum or
>   minimum values supported by System.Decimal, then it is parsed as a
>   System.Double. For example:
>
> 142526.144524 will be converted to a Decimal.
>
> 345262.78036719560925667 will be treated as a Double.